# What is this backtick at the beginning of a directory name? (perl)

Tags: perl

I am trying to understand a program. Correct my if I'm wrong, but backticks are used to execute commands in a shell, so I'm not sure what it is its purpose in the following code:

```
my $end = $` if $dir =~ m/\/foldername/;
foreach my $folder (@dirs_) {
    my $start_from = "$dir" . "\/" . "$folder";
    my $move_to    = "$end" . "\/" . "$folder";
    rmtree $move_to;
    dircopy($start_from, $move_to);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Perl's [built-in punctuation variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%60)!

Comment: (We could probably explain the purpose better if you showed the last regex match in the code prior to this.)

Comment: Thanks everyone, that was fast!

Comment: Please also note that `my $end = $\` if $dir =~ m/\/foldername/` is ***very*** bad practice anyway. The *declaration* is modified as well as the *assignment*, and the exact behaviour depends on undocumented internals of Perl which may change. [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) has this *"The behaviour of a `my`, `state`, or `our` with a statement modifier is undefined"*. You should use `my $end; $end = $\` if $dir =~ m|/foldername|;`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I thought it looked ugly, but I wasn't sure why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not very pretty is it.

The `` $` `` variable is one of the trinity `` $` ``, `$&` and `$'` which represent the pre-match, match, and post-match parts of the last string that was subjected to a successful regex comparison

For instance, if I have

```
my $s = 'abcdef';
```

then after

```
$s =~ /c./;
```

you will find that `` $` `` is `ab`, `$&` is `cd`, and `$'` is `ef`

It's important to remember that, just like the capture variables `$1`, `$2` etc., these three are unaffected by failed regex matches. (They are not set to `undef`.) So it's vital to check whether a regex pattern matched before using any of them

This is archaic Perl, maintained primarily for backward compatability. It was a good idea at the time because Perl was keeping close to shell syntax (as were awk and sed, which still do). Nowadays it is best to use *regex captures*, or perhaps `substr` in conjunction with the newer `@-` and `@+` arrays

All of the special built-in variables are documented in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 5):

The variable `` $` `` is a Perl special variable whose "English" name is `$PREMATCH`.  From the perldoc website:

> The string preceding whatever was matched by the last successful pattern match, not counting any matches hidden within a BLOCK or eval enclosed by the current BLOCK.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Where did you learn about doubling backticks? It's a lot neater than using `<code>` elements. I just wish either one would honour leading and trailing whitespace. It also seems not to work in comments :-/

Comment: @Borodin It's part of the [original Markdown spec](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code), which Stack Exchange (kind of) adheres to. I don't think there's a good way to make it honor leading/trailing whitespace; you can use no-break spaces, but that's a horrible hack. Comments are special: you have to escape backticks with backslashes, so to get `$\`` you have to enter `\`$\\`\``. I don't know why they decided to implement it this way.

Answer (score 4):

The `` $` `` is a regex-related special variable, containing the string preceding the last succesful match. From [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions)

> **$`**
>   The string preceding whatever was matched by the last successful pattern match, not counting any matches hidden within a BLOCK or eval enclosed by the current BLOCK.
>   See Performance issues above for the serious performance implications of using this variable (even once) in your code.
>   This variable is read-only and dynamically-scoped.
>   Mnemonic: ` often precedes a quoted string.

---

In this case it contains the part of the string in `$dir` that precedes the matched `|/foldername|`, if the match happened. Note that this line of code, with the conditional declaration, results in ***undefined behavior*** if there is no match.

The code in `foreach` is then meant to copy folders `"$dir/$folder"` one level up. However, if the match failed this code runs after the program got into an invalid state.  So I would urge you to rewrite it, along the lines of: declare `$end` in a separate statement, then conditionally assign the match and enter the loop, or skip the loop (if the match fails and `$end` is `undef`).

---

Following the link in documentation quote above, to [Performance issues](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Performance-issues)

> In Perl 5.20.0 a new copy-on-write system was enabled by default, which finally fixes all performance issues with these three variables, and makes them safe to use anywhere.

The "three variables" refers to `$\`, `$&`, and `$'`.  Thanks to [stevieb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1334695/stevieb) for this remark.

However, I suggest following the recommendation by [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) to use modern tools and techniques.

Comment: Kudos for mentioning the performance hit. You might want to update your post to note that with the copy-on-write system in v5.20.0, the performance penalty went away. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions

Comment: @stevieb: I have never come across a situation where this was significant, in any version of Perl. It's one of the great taboos of the language, but as soon as you read *anything* from a disk, it's suddenly irrelevant. Not that I would recommend using `$\`` -- the modern ways are clearer

Comment: @stevieb  Thanks, added to post.  However, I completely agree with Borodin's comment and general recommendation.

Comment: @zdim. I too totally agree with Borodin, but I thought it was worthy of note :)

Comment: @stevieb  By all means it is, thank you for binging it up. It belonged there as soon as I decided to quote the whole paragraph.